# Should we avoid usage of Powermock?

Tags: java, testing, powermock, powermockito

In general, Powermock allows us to mock/stub an static behavior or state. For example, we could mock an static method of utility class like `public static String buildKeyFrom(...) {...}` and override its behavior. Or even return our mock instance when target class tries to create an object using constructor of class `new MyService(...)`

Few **examples** of powermock API usage:

`when(StorageKeyUtils.buildKey(id, group, suffixes)).thenReturn("my:group-test:an-id:suffix1")`
`whenNew(MyParser.class).withArguments(factory).thenReturn(parserMock)`

And... it works, actually it helps to avoid refactoring to improve test-ability of our code. You have no more needs to extract static behavior into separate classes, no needs to introduce factories to instantiate new objects and so on.

But, Powermock also have **disadvantages**:

1. Complicated setup.
   In fact, it's not just single *whenSomething* like in Mockito, besides this and replacement of test-runner, you also forced to use `@PrepareForTest` and `PowerMock.mockStatic(..)`. Try to remember what classes to be described within the annotation and inside `mockStatic`, without checking of tests you implemented previously or documentation.
   Sometimes it even works without `mockStatic` while you still trying to mock static methods.
   Of course we could spend some time and investigate documentation to clarify all questions...
2. Bugs and glitches.
   Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Examples:

   1. Conflicts with coverage tools. Due conflicts with instrumenting of classes you may face loss of coverage of your code by test, for example - [JaCoCo](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo)
   2. Try to google for `powermock mbeanserver`... Why powermockito tries to abuse `mbeanserver` and forces us to mark our test-sets with `@PowerMockIgnore`? Since 2013. Bot sometimes it works OK without exclude, why? - idk
   3. Unable to mock static method or constructor passed as lambda by reference, for example: ``
3. It simply encourages usage of *static* - ambassadors of OOP welcome to describe why we mustn't use static methods, etc

**In general**, I would say yes, we should avoid usage of Powermock. One doubtful case I see for it - you have no time for appropriate design of you code to make it testable enough without power-mockito (*, but do you really need that quality of testing, if you don't have time for code-design?*)

What do you think? Do you use Powermock on regular basis? Do you follow some rules while using Powermock on your project?

Comment: If the disadvantages outweigh the advantages in your use case, don't use it. You don't need to make a permanent decision about it.

Comment: @Kayaman, I'm not the person who writes "clean code" right from the beginning. First, I implementing an draft to see how it works, second - analyze how I want to use it and so on... It's always iterative. And every time I have to take into account limitations regarding amount of time I could spend for that task. Maybe it's better to say that we MUST NOT use the library and avoid any trade-off's about code-quality. That is why I'm looking for alternative opinions

Comment: You won't be using any mocking yet if you're writing drafts and throw-away code, so you won't even face the decision of whether to use powermock or not.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, clean code won't need powermock for testing. Because clean code supports dependency injection, is loosely coupled and is easy to unit test so doesn't rely on static methods.

Legacy / dirty code on the other hand is riddled with static methods, is tightly coupled and doesn't support dependency injection. It's these legacy code bases where you'll need powermock for testing

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend PowerMock but life is not always as we would like to have, sometimes you come into project which, let's say, doesn't follow best programming practices, then PowerMock can be accepted in my opinion. Question is a bit too broad.